# Rotated Component Loading Matrix

Tags: python, pca

I'm looking for a way in Python to show the Rotated PCA Component Matrix.

I've written a Python function that takes in a Pandas data frame and returns some of the essential elements of PCA Analysis.  I also have the "varimax" rotation function mentioned elsewhere.  However, I cannot seem to find anything to show the "rotated" component Matrix.  Currently, PCA only shows the un-rotated component loading matrix.  In the first function below, x_comp2 returns the sorted, un-rotated loading matrix.  By contrast, SPSS (and others) will return the rotated loading matrix if you ask for "rotation" as part of the PCA or FA.  The rotated component matrix aids in the interpretation of the variables loading onto each component.

```
#function to run PCA analysis.  yes, I'm sure this can be cleaner... first attempt. x is the name of the dataframe, n is the number of Principal Components to extract.

def pca(x, n):
   pca = PCA(n_components=n)
   l = len(x.columns)
   x_pca = pca.fit(x.iloc[:,0:l])
   pca_t = pca.transform(x.iloc[:,0:l])
   e = pca.explained_variance_
   x_comp = pd.DataFrame(x_pca.components_.T * np.sqrt(x_pca.explained_variance_))
   x_comp['variable'] = np.array(x.columns[0:l])
   x_comp1 = pd.DataFrame(x_comp.set_index('variable'))
   x_comp2 = x_comp1.apply(lambda x: np.where(x < .2,'',round(x,2)))
   x_comp2.sort_values([0,1], ascending=False)
   var=pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.round(x_pca.explained_variance_ratio_, decimals=3)*100))
return x_comp2, var, pca_t, e



#function to perform Varimax rotation
def varimax(Phi, gamma = 1.0, q = 20, tol = 1e-6):
    from scipy import eye, asarray, dot, sum, linalg
    p,k = Phi.shape
    R = eye(k)
    d=0
    for i in range(q):
       d_old = d
       Lambda = dot(Phi, R)
       u,s,vh = linalg.svd(dot(Phi.T,asarray(Lambda)**3 - (gamma/p) * dot(Lambda, np.diag(np.diag(dot(Lambda.T,Lambda))))))
    R = dot(u,vh)
    d = sum(s)
    if d_old!=0 and d/d_old < 1 + tol: break
return dot(Phi, R)
```